# Best practice for cross-repo dependencies

Tags: git, github, version-control, dependency-management

Here is a scenario:

- Repo A is a monster code with a lot of modules and dependencies. It is not easy to install. It is maintained by someone else and hosted on Github.
- Repo A contains a module X which is very useful and has almost no dependencies to the rest of Repo A
- I am maintaining Repo B (hosted on Github), which is small and I hope to make it easy to distribute.
- I would like to use the functionality of module X in Repo B.

Now I can copy module X into Repo B to achieve this. But if the maintainer of Repo A makes a crucial bug fix to module X, there is no way for me to know that. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Assume module X is managed in `branchX` of RepoA, and you want to use the function of module X in `master` branch of RepoB and also want to know if the module X has update in RepoA. So you can add remote of RepoA to RepoB. Detail steps as below:

#### 1.Apply module X (`branchX` in RepoA) in `master` branch of RepoB:

```
# In local RepoB
git remote add repoA <URL for RepoA>
git checkout master
git pull repoA branchX --allow-unrelated-histories
```

**Note:** If there has conflict, you need to modify and save the conflict files and use

```
git add .
git commit
```

#### 2.Check if branchX has update in RepoA:

```
git fetch repoA branchX
```

**If the output likes:**

```
$ git fetch repoA branchX
From https://github.com/account/RepoA
 * branch            branchX          -> FETCH_HEAD
```

That means `branchX` (module X) in RepoA has no update.

**If the output likes:**

```
$ git fetch repoA branchX
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 3 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://github.com/account/RepoA
 * branch            branchX          -> FETCH_HEAD
   65cd100..6abbf6c  branchX          -> repoA/branchX
```

That means there has update in `branchX` (module X) in RepoA, if you want to apply the update of `branchX` into your `master` branch, you can use

```
git checkout master  #If your current branch is not master
git pull repoA branchX
```